# Preventing Capybara from following :method => :delete links

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

My project is using Rails 3 and RSpec and Capybara for testing.

I want to support visitors without javascript, so I've added a 'delete' member to my resource routes. My non-js links look like /posts/3/delete. These then present a form to the user which then does a post request to the destroy action. I'm using extra javascript to strip off the /delete so that the links still work correctly for those who have it turned on.

The problem I've run in to, is that Capybara wants to follow the /posts/3/delete links using an HTTP DELETE request, but it doesn't support the javascript which strips off the /delete. Is there a way I can tell Capybara to just follow all links with HTTP GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is not an option you can simply turn on or off yet, this patch is how I ended up solving this for now.

```
class Capybara::RackTest::Driver < Capybara::Driver::Base
  class Capybara::RackTest::Node < Capybara::Driver::Node
    def click
      if tag_name == 'a'
        driver.follow(:get, self[:href].to_s)
      elsif (tag_name == 'input' and %w(submit image).include?(type)) or
        ((tag_name == 'button') and type.nil? or type == "submit")
        Capybara::RackTest::Form.new(driver, form).submit(self)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Edit: It appears that this will be changed to work this way in version 2. https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/184#issuecomment-1940520